# CSS styling on AngularJS element directive not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, sass

So I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days and can't seem to find a good solution to it.

When I add a class to an AngularJS element directive, the styling shows up in the browser (Chrome) code view but the styles are not being rendered.

I am trying to add a background color to my custom directive element "sss".

Here is my source code:

**_home-header.html** (This is where my element directive "sss" is used)

```
<div class="home-dash-wrapper">
    <tone-today></tone-today>
    <div class="home-dash">
        <set-tone></set-tone>
        <sss></sss>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_sss.html** (This is the template for the element directive)

```
<div class="sign-in">
    <span>Welcome Anonymous | </span><span class="sign-in-button">Sign In</span>
</div>
```

**_sss.scss** (The sass stylesheet that is applying the style)

```
sss{
    background-color: #E9E9EA;
}

.sign-in{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;

    text-align: right;
}
```

**_home.js** (The AngularJS directive declaration)

```
var app = angular.module('tone-home', []);

app.directive('sss', function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/src/templates/modules/_sss.html'
    };
});
```

**Chrome screenshot** (Notice how the background color is set on element "sss" but it's not being rendered in the browser. The "Welcome Anonymous | Sign In" text should be surrounded by this background color as that text is inside the "sss" element.)
[image: Browser isn't rendering background color on sss element]

Comment: odd behavior indeed, can you replicate the issue in a plunker?

Comment: also, have you tried using a class instead? 
.sss{
    background-color: #E9E9EA;
} and <sss class="sss"></sss>

Comment: I am writing this code for the company I work for so I would rather not give out more than what I have (Which I would have to do to make a plunker). But if no solution can be found from what I have given, then I might go ahead and make one.

Yes, I have tried using a class instead. That also does not work...

Comment: Instead of sharing your view and directive, we need to see the rendered DOM elements that show up in your browser debugger.

Comment: @Enzey is correct in his assumption about the browser ignoring the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `display: block;` to your `sss` and you should see the background colour

Answer (score 1):

The element SSS is not understood by the browser so it is being ignored. Using a debugging tool you should see that the SSS element has a size of 0 x 0 and that not element styles you apply to it are respected.

Comment: Ah, yes I see this. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: The only way to make the browser understand the element is to create a new element via WebComponents: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/?redirect_from_locale=ru

This however have very limited browser support at this time.